# SQL Between operator alphabetical results

Tags: sql

How does SQL handle alphabetical comparisons?

```
SELECT * FROM kyle1.dbo.Sheet1$ WHERE First_N BETWEEN 'E' AND 'H'
```

[image: SQL_QUERY]

```
SELECT * FROM kyle1.dbo.Sheet1$ WHERE First_N BETWEEN 'E' AND 'G'
```

[image: SQL_QUERY1]

Why does the first query return two names ('Ellias' and 'George'), when the second query only returns one? ('Ellias')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

it is because `George > G`, you need to compare first letter instead of full comparison

so, in ms sql you can try:

```
SELECT * FROM kyle1.dbo.Sheet1$ WHERE left(First_N, 1) BETWEEN 'E' AND 'G'
```

Answer (score 7):

SQL Comparison basically works like putting the strings in an ordered table.  The table would look like:

```
E
Elias
G
George
H
```

So clearly there is only 1 name between E and G, but two between E and H

Comment: I really like your answer, I am a visual learner and this is a great explanation!